# Explicit Enriques involutions on the Fermat quartic surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces

Let $X$ be the complex Fermat quartic surface defined by the polynomial $x^4+y^4+z^4+w^4$.

By results of Sertöz, we know that the surface $X$ admits at least one Enriques involution, i.e. an involution without fixed points. Is an explicit formula for one such involution already known?

Comment: A remark: any *biregular* involution of $\mathbb{P}^3$ has two lines of fixed points, hence (generically) eight fixed points on $X$. So one cannot hope to get an Enriques involution by the restriction of a biregular  involution of the ambient space. I do not know if there is a construction using a *birational* involution of    $\mathbb{P}^3$.